# Database error while installing custom chart of account module

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14

I'm getting a DB error trying to create a chart of account module for a country that does not have one by default. The module installs correctly. All taxes configured seem to appear fine and the chart of accounts reflects what I have on my `account.acount.template.csv` file. However, going through the log of my terminal, I could see that at the point the csv file mentioned above is loaded, this error occurs

```
2021-03-16 18:32:27,054 68271 INFO testing odoo.modules.loading: loading l10n_foo/data/account.account.template.csv
ERROR testing odoo.sql_db: bad query: 
            INSERT INTO ir_model_data (module, name, model, res_id, noupdate)
            VALUES ('l10n_foo', '10210011', 'account.account.template', 3, false),   
                   ('l10n_foo', '10210012', 'account.account.template', 4, false), 
                    .
                    . 
                    .
                   ('l10n_foo', '10210018', 'account.account.template', 10, false)

ON CONFLICT (module, name)
        DO UPDATE SET (model, res_id, write_date) =
            (EXCLUDED.model, EXCLUDED.res_id, now() at time zone 'UTC')
            
    
ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command 
       have duplicate constrained values.
 
2021-03-16 18:27:21,500 68271 ERROR testing odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Failed to insert ir_model_data
('l10n_foo', '1002010', 'account.account.template', 3, False)
('l10n_foo', '1002011', 'account.account.template', 4, False)
...
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate lines in your **account.acount.template.csv** file,

so please check and remove any one line.

Thanks

Comment: Had almost half a thousand entries so I had to run a duplicate check function on my csv file to spot that one. Cheers.

Comment: Yup smarty, you got it.